# Multiple IIF Criteria in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two fields `A` and `B`. I want an `IIf` condition together to form a field

I am trying to combine two following conditions :

```
IIF(A AND B) IS not NULL,0,0) As Col

IIF(A Is not NULL AND B IS NULL),1,0) As Col
```

How Can I combine these two conditions to form the field Col?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General code example to fit with the original question:

`IIF((Not IsNull(A) AND Not IsNull(B)),0,IIF((Not IsNull(A) AND B IS NULL),1,0))`

Specific answer for your code:

`IIF((Not IsNull(Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL) AND Not IsNull(Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL)),0,IIF((Not IsNull(Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL) AND Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL IS NULL),1,0)) AS dunkel`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than nested IIFs, I like to use switch for readability:

```
Switch(
A is not null and B is not null,0,
A is not null and B is null,1,
True,0)
```

Here's the MS help on the switch function:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379

"True" will always resolve to True, so it acts as an ELSE in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IIF(A IS not null and B IS not NULL, 1, IIF(A Is not NULL AND B IS NULL),1,0)) As Col
```

Comment: I get a Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression error. Here is the statement Replcation A B and Col with the following terms IIF(Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL IS not NULL AND Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL Is not NULL,0,IIF(Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL IS not NULL AND  Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL IS NULL),1,0) AS dunkel