# How to change value from SQL in datagridview using Dapper with MS-Access database in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, dapper

I want to change the value that appears in the datagridview whether there is a solution and for the actual database record information if in union then there are 100,000 but each value of the column "WRH" for each table only has one value unless there is one table that has 2 such values.

The value information I want to change is as follows:

```
001 BECOMES A
002 BECOMES B
003 BECOMES C
```

Or there is another solution please guide me

Thanks

```
Const constrA = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TABLEA.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Const constrB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TABLEB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Const constrC = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TABLEC.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Function GetUsers(constr As String) As IEnumerable(Of Users)
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
      Return con.Query(Of Users)("SELECT * From Users Where WRH ='001' OR WRH ='002' OR WRH ='003'")
        End Using
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   DataGridView1.DataSource = GetUsers(constrA).Union(GetUsers(constrB)).Union(GetUsers(constrC)).ToList
End Sub

Public Class Users
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property Firstname() As String
    Public Property LastName() As String

    Public Property WRH() As String
End Class
```

Table A : `Users`

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | WRH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST1000 | 1000TEST | 001 |
| 2 | TEST2000 | 2000TEST | 001 |

Table B : `Users`

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | WRH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST3000 | 3000TEST | 002 |
| 2 | TEST4000 | 4000TEST | 002 |

Table C : `Users`

| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | WRH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TEST5000 | 5000TEST | 003 |
| 2 | TEST6000 | 6000TEST | 004 |

Desired result in datagridview

| FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | WRH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1000 | 1000TEST | A |
| TEST2000 | 2000TEST | A |
| TEST3000 | 3000TEST | B |
| TEST4000 | 4000TEST | B |
| TEST5000 | 5000TEST | C |

Comment: You can probably simply change the representation of the Column value using the `CellFormatting` event (something like `CharW([Column Value as Integer] + 64)`). If the *conversion* in not actually that simple, you need a mapper (e.g, a Dictionary<string, string>)

Comment: @Jimi , If it converts then it will take a long time to load the data into the DataGridView because the actual database has one hundred thousand records. Please guide from you

Comment: @Jimi , please recommend and guide me using this `CellFormatting event (something like CharW([Column Value as Integer] + 64))` and `you need a mapper (e.g, a Dictionary<string, string>)`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 answers.

First Answer below based on link [Changing datagridview cell color based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380279/changing-datagridview-cell-color-based-on-condition) regularly!

Only for small records

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
        For Each Myrow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows 'Here 2 cell is target value and 1 cell is Volume
            If Myrow.Cells(3).Value.ToString() = "001" Then
                Myrow.Cells(4).Value = "A"
            End If
            If Myrow.Cells(3).Value.ToString() = "002" Then
                Myrow.Cells(4).Value = "B"
            End If
            If Myrow.Cells(3).Value.ToString() = "003" Then
                Myrow.Cells(4).Value = "C"
            End If
        Next Myrow

    End Sub
```

Second Answer below based on link [Multiple IIF Criteria in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279732/multiple-iif-criteria-in-access) regularly!

Only for large records

```
"SELECT ID,Firstname,LastName,WRH,IIF([WRH] ='001','A',IIF([WRH] ='002','B',IIF([WRH] ='003','C'))) AS WRH_Name From Users Where WRH ='001' OR WRH ='002' OR WRH ='003'"
```